# Merge function in Lua

Tags: sorting, merge, lua

Hey, I'm trying to implement the merge function from merge sort in Lua.  I know the algorithm pretty well, but I'm new to Lua.  I keep getting a "bad argument #1 to 'insert' (table expected, got nil)" I believe the error is pointing at my recursive call.  I can't figure it out and I have a feeling it's something pretty trivial.  I just need a Lua guru to give me some guidance.  Thanks.  Here's my function:

```
function merge(l1, l2)
if # l1 == 0 then
    return l2
elseif # l2 == 0    then
    return l1
else
    if l1[1] <= l2[1] then
        tmp = l1[1]
        table.remove(l1,1)
        return table.insert(merge(l1,l2),tmp)

    else 
        tmp = l2[1]
        table.remove(l2,1)
        return table.insert(merge(l1,l2),tmp)
    end
end
end
```

Answer (score 6):

I am not completely sure what you want to achieve with the `merge` function, but a clear problem is that `table.insert` doesn't return a table, it returns `nil`.

Storing the result of the merge in table `t`, using `table.insert` on `t` and finally returning `t` doesn't seem to break as before.

```
function merge(l1, l2) 
    if #l1 == 0 then
        return l2
    elseif # l2 == 0 then
        return l1
    else
        if l1[1] <= l2[1] then
            local tmp = table.remove(l1, 1)
            local t = merge(l1, l2) 
            table.insert(t, tmp)
            return t
        else 
            local tmp = table.remove(l2, 1)
            local t = merge(l1, l2) 
            table.insert(t, tmp)
            return t
        end 
    end 
end
```

A note on the few other modifications I did. `table.remove` returns the removed element, so you don't have to first access the element and then remove it. I recommend using the keyword `local` for variables, because in Lua all variables are global by default.

Comment: Hey.  Thanks for the tips!  It worked great!  The merge function takes two already sorted tables and merges them into one sorted table.  I had to change the table.insert(t, tmp) to table.insert(t, 1, tmp) so that it would insert the item at the beginning of the return table.

Comment: Mike K, I think you forgot to mark ponzao's answer as correct.